# java.rmi.remote Exception ejb Exception nested exception is; com.bbn.amazon

Tags: java

```
java.rmi.RemoteException:  EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 


 com.bbn.amazon.util.AppException: file not found null\application.properties


 Reason: null\application.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)


at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:234)


at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.
java:348)

at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:259)
at
```

com.ff.carnegie.ejb.bl.xmleventpac.XMLEventFactoryBean_7u2fts_EOImpl_1034_WLStub.getEventXMLByIds(Unknown Source)

```
at org.carnegiehall.browser.XMLPrintWriter.writeXML(XMLPrintWriter.java:91)


at org.carnegiehall.browser.EventManager.performExportXML(EventManager.java:2865)


at org.carnegiehall.browser.EventManager.exportCurrentCalendar(EventManager.java:2745)

at org.carnegiehall.browser.EventManager.exportSelectedCalendarItems(EventManager.java:2555)


at org.carnegiehall.browser.EventManager.exportItem_actionPerformed(EventManager.java:2283)


at org.carnegiehall.browser.CHFrame$SymAction.actionPerformed(CHFrame.java:1653)


at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)


at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)


at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)


at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)


at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:357)


at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1223)
```

javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1264)

```
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:272)


at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6267)


at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)


at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6032)


at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)

at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)

at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)

at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)

at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)

at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)

at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)

at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)

at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)

at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)

at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)


at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

please suggest to resolve the issue. your effort is highly appreciatable.

Comment: it seems your app is missing some directory. [com.bbn.amazon.util.AppException: file not found null\application.properties]. What "null" was supposed to be?

Comment: same code is running in the production environment but in the test environment it throws above  exception we have compare the directory structure all are same null is the path of the application.properties files

Comment: when I said "missing some directory" I did not mean that your environment has one directory less (sorry, my bad). Instead, I meant that somewhere in your app some variable is being defined. Since it was not defined in your test env, the string was built with "null". From your stacktrace, there's no way to know where exactly is the problem.